# Using the hash function

Tags: c, linux, hash, hashtable

I'm doing my homework with `LINUX` and I have some question about hash function.
When I input `*mnemonic_name` into some character string like `'ADD'`, the `find_index` is random every time when I compile. Would you explain this problem and solve it for me?

Here is my code:

```
251  int symtab_finder(char *mnemonic_name)
252  {
253      node *temp;
254 
255      int find_index  =   op_find(mnemonic_name);
256      int find_flag   =   0;
257 
258      temp    =   optabl[find_index].head;
259 
260      while(temp)
261      {
262          if((strcmp(temp->mnemonic_name,mnemonic_name)==0))
263          {
264              find_flag   =   1;
265          }
266          temp    =   temp->next;
267 
268      }
269      if(find_flag == 0)
270      {
271 
272      }
273      printf("name %s, flag %d, find index %d\n",mnemonic_name,find_flag, find_index);
274      return find_flag;
275  }
```

When I put in string like 'ADD' into the '*mnemonic_name' variable, the output 'find_index' is random! I do not know why this happens.

Here's my op_find code below.

```
 44  int op_find(char *mnemonic_name)
 45  {
 46      int op_index;
 47      int i;
 48      for(i=0; i< strlen(mnemonic_name); i++)
 49      {
 50          op_index += mnemonic_name[i];
 51      }
 52 
 53  //  printf("op_index is %d\n",op_index % 20);
 54      return op_index = op_index % 20;
 55  }
 56 
 57  int mn_find(char *opcode_number)
 58  {
 59      int opcode_value;
 60      opcode_value = hex_to_dec(opcode_number);
 61  //  printf("mne value is %d\n",((opcode_value/4)%20));
 62      return ((opcode_value/4)%20);
 63  }
```

Comment: You should initialize your variables. As op_index is not initialized, it may get a random value.

Comment: Wow!! Francis! thanks!! this is really hard to find this timid problem.. Thanks again!!

Comment: Only that about every compiler warns about this situation, so always use `-Wall`

Comment: hello hroptayr! thanks your comment! but my LINUX machine cannot warn it to me even though I using '-Wall' opearation into a 'makefile'. Anyway, thank to your kindness and have a good day!

Comment: Then you have something wrong somewhere (perhaps in your `makefile`). You really *should* always *use* `-Wall`, and you should avoid most warnings (the very few you don't well to avoid should have big comments in the code for explanation....)

Comment: You should also always include -Werror. It's the only way to ensure that the warnings stay away.

Answer (score 1):

OK. So just for the sake of removing this from the 'unanswered' section I am re-adding the answer already given by Francis:

```
int op_index; // <-- not initialized.
```

And make sure to use -Wall in compiler flags.

(additionally added +1 to Francis comment.)